# Why does jQuery fail to attach a mouseover handler to a Flash object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

For some reason, jQuery (1.6.2) fails to attach a mouseover handler to a Flash object.

Amusingly, `getElementById().onmouseover = ...` works as expected.

```
// fail
$('#content-banner').mouseover(function () {alert(1)});
// success
document.getElementById("content-banner").onmouseover = function (evt) { alert(3); };
```

See the [live example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaCp7/5/) for details.

What prevents jQuery from attaching the handler?

---

**Update**

A quick fix would be to use `live()` as suggested by [ShankarSangoli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042648/why-does-jquery-fail-to-attach-a-mouseover-handler-to-a-flash-object/7042749#7042749). However the question still remains. **Why does jQuery fail to attach the handler?**

Comment: I don't know why, but a workaround could be to put the `object` in a `div` and attach the handler to the `div`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery does not support `data()` on `<applet>`, `<embed>`, and `<object>`. Since jQuery's event handler stack depends on `data()` to work, thus calling `mouseover()` on an object would fail.

So, as long as you don't use jQuery's event handing you would do fine:

```
var banner = $('#content-banner');
banner.live ( 'mouseover', ... ); // works, becuse live hooks to document not to banner
banner[0].onmouseover = ... ; // works
banner[0].addEventListener('mouseover', ... , false); // also works
```

If you dig into the code you can see that there is an exception for objects with `classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000'`, which is Flash, however classid only works for IE.  So, the short answer is avoid using jQuery events on objects.

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery `live`. <strike>Since the flash is initialized after the page is loaded so it is not able to find the element.</strike> Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xaCp7/6/)

---

**Update**

Reiterating [Sheepy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042648/why-does-jquery-fail-to-attach-a-mouseover-handler-to-a-flash-object/7058605#7058605): jQuery maintains the event handlers in `data` of the dom element but since it does not support data() on  the events are never attached. The alternative is to use `live` which will attach the event on the root document but will work as expected.

Comment: `live()` works but are You sure it's about initialization? It seems a bit odd that `getElementById()` finds the element whereas jQuery doesn't.

Comment: Where are you executing `getElementById()`?

Comment: May be after the flash is initialized it looses the events attached through jquery which is not the case when we use `getElementById` and attach handler to `onmouseover` event directly.

Comment: Try executing `$('#content-banner').mouseover(function () {alert(1)});` manually from console after everything has been initialized. It still fails. Let's see if someone can come up with the "why".

Comment: Are you trying `$('#content-banner')..mouseover(function () {alert(1)});` this in fiddle?

Comment: fiddle uses `iframe` so if you execute that in console jQuery will not find element.

Comment: No, it's executed locally. The element itself is accessible.

Comment: @Saul - I think there is some issue with jquery, but for now you can use live and accept this answer :)

Comment: Interesting. This: `$('#content-banner').live('click', function () {alert(1);});` fails...

Comment: @All - I think when flash in initialized it overrides all the events attached directly on the element by `jQuery`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: Actually, as it turned out, the root cause was that jQuery does not support `data()` on `<applet>`, `<embed>`, and `<object>`. See [Sheepy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042648/why-does-jquery-fail-to-attach-a-mouseover-handler-to-a-flash-object/7058605#7058605).