# Error when using event mousemove can't hidden value when mousemove on object swf?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
oj = ["a","img","object"];
jQuery(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    jQuery("#arrow").css({
        top : e.pageY - 10,
        left : e.pageX + 35
    })
    jQuery.each(oj, function(i, val) {
        jQuery(val).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery("div[id^=\'arrow\']").hide()
        });
        jQuery(val).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery("div[id^=\'arrow\']").show()
        })
    }) 
});
</script>
```

And html (swf + a)

```
<object height="90" width="380">
    <param name="movie" value="banner.swf">
    <param vmode="transparent" value="opaque" name="wmode">
    <embed height="90" width="380" vmode="transparent" wmode="opaque" src="banner.swf">
</object>
<a href="index.html">test</a>
<div id="arrow">arrow</div>
```

When I mousemove on `a tag` is result hidden `<div id="arrow">arrow</div>`, But when mousemove on `object swf` is result not hidden value `<div id="arrow">arrow</div>`, How to fix it ? [demo mine here](http://jsfiddle.net/trrc8/)

Answer (score 0):

You should write your jquery code in 
`$(document).ready(function(){
//code here
});`

Also `top`,`left` works with `position` so add a line in your code

```
jQuery("#arrow").css({
    top : e.pageY - 10,
    left : e.pageX + 35,
    position:'relative'
})
```

Here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/trrc8/1/

Comment: When you mouse on flash, result arrow has been hidden

Comment: You want to add this functionality
`jQuery.each(oj, function(i, val) {
        jQuery(val).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery("div[id^=\'arrow\']").hide()
        });
        jQuery(val).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery("div[id^=\'arrow\']").show()
        })
    }) ` outside the `document mousemove` or inside it because the above code is initialized after `document mousemove`

Comment: One more thing 
jQuery does not support `data()` on `<applet>`, `<embed>`, and `<object>`. Since `jQuery's event handler` stack depends on `data()` to work, thus calling `mouseover()` on an `object` would fail. For more info read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042648/why-does-jquery-fail-to-attach-a-mouseover-handler-to-a-flash-object